# How to Identify a new value

Tags: mysql, sql-server, return-value

I have 3 tables joined to each other to get information of my clients. some of my clients are multiracial and that makes the table to have duplicate rows.
I was wondering if I can identify a new value and say if an ID duplicate, in race gave me Multiracial as a value?
I have this:

```
ID     Name     Age   Race
4000    Duc      25    Philipino
4000    Duc      25    Chinese
4001    Daniel   36    African American
4002    Nicole   20    White
4002    Nicole   20    Middle East
```

I want to have this

```
ID      Name      Age    Race
4000    Duc       25     Multiracial
4001    Daniel    36     African American
4002    Nicole    20     Multiracial
```

I really appreciate any help

Comment: so this is msft sql server? you have a cte answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that (should work on MS SQL and MySQL):

```
SELECT ID,Name,Age, CASE WHEN COUNT(Race)>1 THEN 'Mulitiracial' ELSE MAX(Race) END Race
FROM Src
GROUP BY ID,Name,Age
```

To test your data (CTE only in MS SQL) I've used following:

```
WITH Src AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (4000, 'Duc   ', 25, 'Philipino'        ),
    (4000, 'Duc   ', 25, 'Chinese'          ),
    (4001, 'Daniel', 36, 'African American' ),
    (4002, 'Nicole', 20, 'White           ' ),
    (4002, 'Nicole', 20, 'Middle East     ' )
    )T (ID,Name,Age,Race)
)
SELECT ID,Name,Age, CASE WHEN COUNT(Race)>1 THEN 'Mulitiracial' ELSE MAX(Race) END Race
FROM Src
GROUP BY ID,Name,Age
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(SELECT ID,NAME,AGE,RACE,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID,NAME,AGE ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS CNT
FROM
#TEMP
)
SELECT ID,NAME,AGE,CASE WHEN CNT>1 THEN 'MULTIRACILA' ELSE RACE END
FROM CTE
GROUP BY 
ID,NAME,AGE,CASE WHEN CNT>1 THEN 'MULTIRACILA' ELSE RACE END
```

Comment: I really appreciate your time TheGameiswar!